# extract specific values from firebase database

Tags: reactjs, jsx, reduce

Given this database from firebase can someone tell me how to obtain the average score from the 2 data?
i have tried the following code but with no success. I believe the issue is on how to exactly extract the score value from the data.

CODE I HAVE TRIED

```
<h3>Average total: {Object.values(learnerObjects).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)/(learnerObjects.length || 1)}</h3>
```

DATABASE

```
learners
       -MZKJfb-sDiNkSxFcqu4
       email: 
        "pepe365@yahoo.com"
       firstName: 
        "Gian"
       lastName: 
        "Peppin"
       score: 
        "10"

      -MZN_V_YFt2naSReI4FA
        email: 
         "may56@gmail.com"
        firstName: 
         "feona"
        lastName: 
         "may"
         score: 
         "8"

{
    "-MZKJfb-sDiNkSxFcqu4": {
        "email": "pepe365@yahoo.com",
        "firstName": "Gian",
        "lastName": "Peppin",
        "score": "10"
    },
    "-MZN_V_YFt2naSReI4FA": {
        "email": "may56@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "feona",
        "lastName": "may",
        "score": "8"
    },
    "-MZOBLhg1liCtmsG1M10": {
        "email": "ciccio90@yahoo.com",
        "firstName": "teo",
        "lastName": "mammuccari",
        "score": "7"
    },
    "-MZOBWPymXWdqjknKpfu": {
        "email": "greenarr56@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "mirko",
        "lastName": "de luca",
        "score": "5"
    },
    "-MZR2K_Cwkcqbz-UFlsN": {
        "email": "fester80@yahoo.com",
        "firstName": "Salvatore",
        "lastName": "De Gennaro",
        "score": "7"
    },
    "-MZR7AQggg222CYFFII_": {
        "email": "pepti89@aol.com",
        "firstName": "Nikhil",
        "lastName": "Piparia",
        "score": "6"
    }
}
```

Comment: well basically I would just like to know how to tap in the score value, coz by doing Object.values(learnerObjects) I am only getting all values from the single data and not the score, which is the one I am interested in

Comment: -MZKJfb-sDiNkSxFcqu4: {email: "pepe365@yahoo.com", firstName: "Gian", lastName: "Peppin", score: "10"}

Comment: Change `b` to `b.score`?

Comment: And `learnerObjects` is not an `Array`, it's an `Object`. Simply divide the total score by `Object.values(learnerObjects).length`.

Comment: i have tried it. its given me the values displaying it inline but not added it. I have tried to obtain at least the total sum but nothing. this is what it displays "Average total: 01087576"

Comment: Then write: `parseInt(b.score)` to explicitly cast strings to integers.

Comment: that was it thanks Janez!